# Spring Batch: How can i set record separator policy in FlatFileItemWriter?

Tags: spring-batch, record, double-quotes, separator, itemwriter

I need to write record with the same reading format.
Example:

```
aaa;bbb;ccc;dd
dd;zzz
```

What I need is to attach the record with double quotes:

```
aaa;bbb;ccc;"dd
dd";zzz
```

How can i do it? In FlatFileItemReader there is the option to use RecordSeparatorPolicy which does, but in FlatFileItemWriter???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `RecordSeparatorPolicy` on the writer side. You need a custom [LineAggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/LineAggregator.html) for this use case.

Comment: Sure in line aggregator or in the processor i can modify the data but i was hoping for a more painless solution :)